# Magento Importer Images

Tags: image, magento, import

I'm trying to import images in the magento importer but nothings appearing. I've gone through all the threads and I'm sure I've done everything I'm supposed to do and now I'm at a complete loss for what the problem could be.

I've created a folder called "import" in my "media" folder and placed the image 'blog-1.jpg' in it and my data is saved in a .csv and it looks similar to this: (i've copied the entries manually for readability)

```
sku - test1
name - test1
description - Test
short_description - Test
status - 1
visibility - 4
tax_class - 2
qty - 1
price - 1
weight - 1
image - /blog-1.jpg
image_label - Hello
small_image - /blog-1.jpg
small_image_label - Hello
thumbnail - /blog-1.jpg
thumbnail_label - Hello
```

When I "check" my data it says the data is fine and its found a field. Everything else gets imported correctly but when I click on "images" it has no images in there.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your image are store in `media>import` folder.

Then in your csv file just write in image column `/imagename.jpg`

It will find same imagename in import folder if image exist then it will upload the image.

---

I'm sorry to say, but there is more going on behind the scenes with magento images that it simply putting a filename in the database and linking to your image. The cache generation alone is pretty complex. I believe you are going to have a hard time doing it the way you are attempting.

That being said, I do have a suggestion. Since your images are already on the server, I suggest you write a simple php script to tell magento to attach them to the product image. This could be automated, but i'll give you a small example below...

To attach an image, you would simply navigate to the url like this http://yoursite.com/imageattacher.php?sku=YOURSKU&image=yourimagefilename.jpg

The script would be like this... create a file in your magento ROOT and call it imageattacher.php. Upload your images to the magento media import directory. I have not tested this but it should work.

```
<?php
    // Initialize magento for use outside of core
    umask(0);
    require_once 'app/Mage.php';
    Mage::app('admin');

    // Get the variables from the URL
    $sku = $_GET["sku"];
    $imageName = $_GET["image"];

    // get the image from the import dir
    $import = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import/' . $imageName;

    // Load the product by sku
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku);

    // if the product exists, attempt to add the image to it for all three items
    if ($product->getId() > 0)
    {
        // Add the images and set them for their respective usage (the radio button in admin)
        $product->addImageToMediaGallery($import,array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'),false,false);

        // Make the changes stick
        $product->save();
    }
?>
```